# Pig - counting members across a group

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Say I have a relation `Students`, with fields `grade` and `teacher`. I want to group by both grade and teacher, but retain a count of all the students per grade in each group. Something like:

```
classes = GROUP Students BY (grade,teacher);
classes = FOREACH classes {
   GENERATE
      (### COUNT OF ALL STUDENTS IN GRADE ###) as grade_size,
      Students as students,
      teacher as teacher;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do the filter from inside the group statement. Some kind of filter, but I don't know to scope the grade of the students outside vs. inside the group.

Comment: Removed the sql tag because this is explicitly about Pig.

Comment: sample input and output would help understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing it:

1) Using Group By grade and teacher, than count, than Flatten and Group By grade.

```
classes = GROUP Students BY (grade,teacher);
teachers = FOREACH classes GENEARATE FLATTEN(group) as (grade,teacher), COUNT(Students) as perTeacehr;
grade = GROUP teachers BY grade;
result = FOREACH grade GENERATE FLATTEN(teachers), SUM(teachers.perTeacher) as perGrade;
describe result;
dump result;
```

2) Group By grade, than use UDF from [BagGroup](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.2.0/datafu/pig/bags/BagGroup.html) from DataFu library to do in memory group by, but this is vulnerable to possible heap memory exceptions, but is faster.